# Dynamic attribute setting for Golang struct

Tags: go, dynamic

I have two structs that are of different types but have similar attributes.
Is it possible to create a function that will set both structs of different types attributes?  I don't want to have to write out 2 separate functions.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
type Test1 struct {
    suite.Suite
    name      string
    age       int64
    field1    string
}

type Test2 struct {
    suite.Suite
    name      string
    age       int64
    field2    int64
}

func (t *Test1) setT1() {
    setValues(t)
}

func (t *Test2) setT2() {
    setValues(t)
}

func setValues(t interface{}) {
    t.name = "name"
    t.age = 4
}
```

Here's what I don't want to do:

```
type Test1 struct {
    suite.Suite
    name      string
    age       int64
    field1    string
}

type Test2 struct {
    suite.Suite
    name      string
    age       int64
    field2    int64
}

func (t *Test1) setT1() {
    t.name = "name"
    t.age = 4
}

func (t *Test2) setT2() {
    t.name = "name"
    t.age = 4
}
```

Is this possible in some way?

Comment: You can define a new struct containing common elements, define this func as a method for that struct, and embed that struct into two separate structs.

Answer (score 2):

Create a struct with common fields

```
type Test struct{
  name      string
  age       int64
}
```

Then embedded `Test` in both `Test1` and `Test2`

```
type Test1 struct {
    Test
    field1    string
}

type Test2 struct {
    Test
    field2    int64
}
```

The exported parameters and methods defined on the embedded type are accessible through the embedding type.
So, define the method for `Test`

```
func (t *Test) setT(){
    t.name = "name"
    t.age = 4
}
```

Now you can access `.setT()` for both `Test1` and `Test2`

```
var t1 Test1
t1.setT()
```

Full code in go playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Z1jlP2XzuZ-)